# How to create array in PHP for google charts

Tags: php, arrays, charts

I want to create an array in PHP to use with Google Chart.

This is the code I tried, but doesn't work.

Where Y=$r and X=$x_n_2;

```
for($r=1; $r<=4; $r++){
  for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
    $x_n_1=$i+1;
    $x_n=$i;
    $x_n_2=$r*$x_n*(1-$x_n);
   echo $x_n_2.'<br>' ; 
  }
}
```

This is the array I want:

```
$data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Y', 'X', ],
            ['1',0],
            ['',-2],
            ['',-6],
            ['',-12],
            ['',-20],
            ['',-30],
            ['',-42],
            ['',-56],
            ['',-72],
            ['2',0],
            ['',-6],
            ['',-18],
            ['',-36],
            ['',-60],
            ['',-90],
            ['',-126],
            ['',-168],
            ['', -216],
           ...
```

Is there any way to do that automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would create a PHP array:

```
for($r=1; $r<=4; $r++){
  for($i=1; $i<10; $i++){
     $chart[i+1] = array($i,$r*$i*(1-$i));
   }
 }
```

Not sure I got the element equations correct, but you should get the idea.

To create an array in PHP to be used in JavaScript:
**This Code is Tested**

```
    $js = 'var chart = [';   // start JavaScript array

    for($r=1; $r<=4; $r++){
      for($x=1; $x<10; $x++){
         $y = $r*$i*(1-$i);
         $js .= "[$x,$y],";    // append set of array elements
       }
     }
     $js = substr($js,0,-1) . "];\n";  // remove last comma, close array, end line
    echo <<<EOT    // add the array ($js) to JavaScript
    <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
    $js
    //]]>
    </script>
    EOT;
```

**The comment after** `echo <<<EOT` **must be removed, nothing is allowed on the line after EOT, not even a space.**

The `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` are not comments, they are there to tell the HTML parser not to parse JavaScript as HTML.  I use them to eliminate errors reported by the W3C HTML Markup Validator.

### Results:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
var chart = [[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0],[9,0]];

//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Yes Sir, your array is correct. but i don't get how to input it into  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([.......])

Comment: I know PHP arrays.  I do not use anything Google.  I even use Yahoo Search.  I read Google's Terms of Service and Privacy Policy, and it is a BIG no go with me.  Nobody reads the ToS, except me, the whole thing.

Comment: I took a quick look at Google Charts and saw the JavaScript array used.  This should help.